# "Парикмахерская" как заменитель местоимения в любительских рассказах

Tags: стилистика

У меня такой вопрос и просьба о помощи.
Бывает, что меня просят вычитать фанфики (кто не в курсе, это любительские сочинения на тему каких-либо фильмов, книг и т.д. — продолжения, ответвления сюжета и т.д.). О низком качестве большинства из них я сейчас говорить не буду, а спрошу вот, о чем.
Среди фанфикописцев сейчас очень модно (точнее, кто-то один начал, а остальные стали повторять) заменять имя персонажа или местоимение (она, он) словами "блондин", "брюнет", "длинноволосая" и прочей парикмахерской. Режет ужасно, потому что употребляется очень часто и там, где совсем нет нужды обращать внимание читателя на прическу и цвет волос героя. Причем, такое встречается и во вполне приличных текстах. Я вижу, что это некрасиво, криво и неграмотно. Но у меня нет убедительных аргументов, чтобы объяснить это "юным дарованиям".
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Примеры хорошо бы...
Пока не вижу ничего плохого в блондине. Даже если он высокий и в черном ботинке.

Comment: Чего же ждать от непрофессионалов?

Comment: Не стоит забывать, что профессионалы строили "Титаник", а любители — Ноев ковчег))) Есть очень много отличных произведений, написанных любителями, и миллион ерунды за авторством филологов.

Comment: Тут же говорится о массовом явлении, а в массе все талантами быть не могут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попросите назвать цвет волос героев, уважаемых фанфикописцем классиков. После чего спросите почему он если и вспомнил, то не без труда. Любая характеристика персонажа должна иметь  смысл. Если постоянно подчёркиваются волосы, то они должны иметь какое-то значение в данном эпизоде. В противном случае, смотрится нелепо.

Comment: Блондинко?

Comment: Примерно так. Я навскидку смог лишь вспомнить, что Элен Курагина у Л. Н. Толстого была блондинкой, а Наташа Ростова - брюнеткой. И то потому, что они противопоставлялись в сцене первого бала Наташи.

Comment: Вот именно что нелепо, когда это используется как равноценный заменитель местоимения или имени.

Comment: Нелепо, когда "не читал, но осуждаю".
Может, конечно, тут все настолько перечитали произведений упомянутого жанра, что все понимают, о чем речь идет, но мне "блондинко" ухо не режет.

Answer (score 3):

С одной стороны - мода, как Вы сказали.  С другой - возможно, желание избежать частого повторения "он",  "она". А вот как избежать - не каждый догадается.

Кстати, мне иногда попадались детективы, написанные от первого лица. Там в каждой строчке "я". Раздражает ужасно. Но, думаю, называть самого себя "блондином", "усатым", "коротко стриженным" и т.п. даже фанфикописцы не решатся.